# login popup loading full page in partial view on success in mvc?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I have an issue whereby the ajax form in my login popup loads the homepage into a partial view on success.  When there is a failure or validation issue the partial view is reloaded but it should not when login is successful.

Ajax form in Navbar:

```
<li class="login">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" tabindex="5"><span>Login</span></a>
                    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, new AjaxOptions
                    {
                        HttpMethod = "POST",
                        UpdateTargetId = "login_box"

                    }, new { id = "login_box" }))
                    {
                        @Html.Action("loginform", "Home")
                    }
                </li>
```

This then loads the content of the form from a shared partial view name _loginpartial (shortened):

```
<div class="login_box_lower">
    <p class="login_box_or">or</p>
    <p class="login_sign_in">Sign in</p>
    <div style="position:relative;">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "Email", maxlength = "30", @class = "login_username clearable" } })
        <span class="login_username_icon"></span>
    </div>
    <div style="position:relative;">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "Password", maxlength = "18", @class = "login_pw clearable" } })
        <span class="login_pw_icon"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="rememberbox" >
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe, new { @class = "remembercheck" })
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
    </div>

    <input type="submit" class="login_button" value="Log in" />
```

The controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return PartialView("_LoginPartial", model);
        }

        // Require the user to have a confirmed email before they can log on.
        var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
        if (user != null)
        {
            if (!await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id))
            {
                string callbackUrl = await SendEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account-Resend");


                ViewBag.errorMessage = "You must have a confirmed email to log on. "
                                     + "The confirmation token has been resent to your email account.";
                return View("Error");
            }
        }


        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return PartialView("_LoginPartial", model);
        }
    }
```

The RedirectToLocal action is as per the default:

```
private ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
    {
        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
        {
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

So as I see it if the login is successful and the returnUrl string is null then the home index view should be returned?  Why is it only being returned in the partial view of the login popup?

Additionally my returnURL string generated at the start of the Ajax form doesn't seem to work, so if anyone could suggest to me where I am going wrong with that it would be very helpful.  Thanks.

Comment: Because the whole point of ajax is to stay on the same page. If your wanting to redirect after a successful login, then do not use ajax. Do a normal submit

Comment: That's very obvious now I think about it, thanks.

Comment: I realised why I had used an Ajax form in the first place, that was the only way I could find of returning the form within a partial view when some sort of validation failed.  I'm not sure how exactly I can do this using a regular form, returning a partial view simply loads the partial view by itself.  Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: The reason for using ajax is to improve performance. You have said you have your _"ajax form in Navbar"_, suggesting its in every page so you generating all that extra html in every page despite that fact that its only needed once per session - you likely to be degrading performance, not improving it. Why are you not just following the normal pattern - i.e if the user navigates to a method marked with `[Authorize]`, then they are automatically redirected to the login page, and if successful, back to the page they were navigating to?

Comment: The idea is to have the login as a popup on all pages, so a user can login whilst staying on the same page, without being redirected to a separate login page.  I have seen sites doing this and assumed it was fairly standard practice, are you suggesting that having a login popup like this in the navbar will significantly slow the site down?  Is there a better way of having a Login popup appear on each page without doing it the way I am currently?

Comment: There is no problem making an 'ajax' login available in all pages, but make it a link/button that loads the login form using ajax so its only generated once as needed rather that generating the extra html in every page